# Cannot access the nested objects's data in render function using React useState

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, use-state

I want to display `user` object's data on the page. Initially, I have
set the `cats` value to be an empty array using the `useState` which
you can see below.

```
useEffect(() => {
             fetchItems();
         }, []);
     
         const [cats, setcats] = useState([]);
     
         const fetchItems = async () => {
             const data = await fetch("https://cat-fact.herokuapp.com/facts/");
             const cats = await data.json();
             setcats(cats.all);
     };
```

Below is my render function.

```
    <div>
        <h1>Shop Page</h1>
        <hr />
    
        {cats.map((cat) => (
            <div key={cat._id}>
                <strong>Id: </strong>{" "}
                <Link to={`/Shop/${cat._id}`} style={linkstyle}>
                    {cat._id}
                </Link>
                <br />
                <strong>Text: </strong> {cat.text}
                <br />
                <strong>Upvotes: </strong> {cat.upvotes}
                <strong>UserName: </strong>
                {cat.user.name.first}
                {/* Above line is not working */}
                <p>{JSON.stringify(cat.user)}</p>
                {/* Above line actually prints the complete data in a cat objects's data including first name and last name */}
                <hr />
            </div>
        ))}
    </div>
```

I am getting the following error.

```
    TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined
    (anonymous function)
    E:/online study/learn_react/react-router/src/Shop.js:38
      35 | <br />
      36 | <strong>Upvotes: </strong> {cat.upvotes}
      37 | <hr />
    > 38 | <strong>UserName: </strong>
         | ^  39 | {cat.user.name.first}
      40 | {/* Above line is not working */}
      41 | <p>{JSON.stringify(cat.user)}</p>
```

However `JSON.stringify(cat.user)` seems to work fine and display the
info in string format on the page.

`https://cat-fact.herokuapp.com/facts/` response is the following.

```
    {
        "all": [
            {
                "_id": "58e009550aac31001185ed12",
                "text": "The oldest cat video on YouTube dates back to 1894.",
                "type": "cat",
                "user": {
                    "_id": "58e007480aac31001185ecef",
                    "name": {
                        "first": "Kasimir",
                        "last": "Schulz"
                    }
                },
                "upvotes": 6,
                "userUpvoted": null
            },
            {
                "_id": "58e008340aac31001185ecfb",
                "text": "Cats sleep 70% of their lives.",
                "type": "cat",
                "user": {
                    "_id": "58e007480aac31001185ecef",
                    "name": {
                        "first": "Kasimir",
                        "last": "Schulz"
                    }
                },
    ]
    }
```

I cannot understand what is the error I am making or the point I am
overlooking. Please help me with this.

Thanks in Advance.

Attached are some screenshots for the reference.

[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/rSNIn.png   [2]:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/EMVS1.png   [3]:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/lk05x.png

**Edit**

I have found the solution from the answers given by the community. My code was correct but the `user` object seems to be missing in one of the responses which I didn't notice and also didn't filter out bad responses, which led to this error.

Comment: Your code is _mostly_ fine, it's just that somewhere in the hundreds of response objects at least one is missing the `user` property, so you'll need to use guards or optional chaining.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The response from `https://cat-fact.herokuapp.com/facts/` includes a `cat` that is missing the `user` property

```
{
  _id: "58e008450aac31001185ecfd", 
  text: "A cat was mayor of Talkeetna, Alaska, for 20 years…His name is Stubbs, and he died on July 23, 2017.", 
  type: "cat", 
  upvotes: 1, 
  userUpvoted: null
}
```

Either fix the data or e.g. filter it out:

```
setcats(cats.all.filter(c => c.user));
```

Answer (score 0):

A user property doesn't exist this Id: 58e008450aac31001185ecfd

you can try this :
{ cat.user && cat.user.name.first}